# jQuery UI Dialog Box wont reopen after close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's the code i'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.addNew').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                openEditor(event);
            }); /* END ADD CLICK */

            $('.editLink').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                openEditor(event);
            }); /* END EDIT CLICK */

            /* DEFINE THE EDITOR OPEN LATER */
            $('.viewer').dialog({
                fullscreen: true,
                show: "pulsate",
                width: $(window).width()-20,
                height: $(window).height(),
                autoOpen: false
            }); /* END OPEN EDITOR */

        }); /* END DOCUMENT READY */

        function openEditor(event) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('.viewer').load(window.location.pathname + 'edit.php');
                var x =event.pageX - ( $(document).scrollLeft() - 100 );
                var y =event.pageY -$(document).scrollTop();
                $('.viewer').dialog('open');
            }); /* END DOCUMENT READY */
        } /* END OPENEDITOR FUNCTION */
```

The dialog box opens just fine the first time, but if I close the dialog box by clicking on the Close button or hitting escape it doesn't open the second time.  This is the error message that i'm getting in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
$('.viewer').dialog('open');
```

I was originally not using autoOpen: false which I thought was the problem, but when I switched to doing it this way it still gave the same error.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've been digging around some more and it appears to be caused by the $('.viewer').load('filename'); line. For some reason that only allows the viewer to be opened once.

Comment: are your buttons dynamically generated?

Comment: No but the content within the viewer is loaded via an Ajax call and I think that might be causing the problem.  It's almost like the jQuery inside of the ajax loaded page is interfering with the other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it was because I was re-including jQuery on the page I was loading into the Viewer class, so I guess you can't re-include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're re-trying to launch the dialog by calling openEditor? If that is the case, try removing the inner call to document ready

```
function openEditor(event) {
    $('.viewer').load(window.location.pathname + 'edit.php');
    var x =event.pageX - ( $(document).scrollLeft() - 100 );
    var y =event.pageY -$(document).scrollTop();
    $('.viewer').dialog('open');
} /* END OPENEDITOR FUNCTION */
```

Comment: Tried that, still get the exact same error, with or without the inner document ready.  (That is added for easy no-conflict jQuery).

Comment: I just created a fiddle and it seems to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DkdCT/ (note: I commented out the viewer load line for the sake of the fiddle)

Comment: I just updated the question, I discovered that without the Ajax load of content into the viewer it works fine.

For some reason that $('.viewer').load() is messing up the dialog box and only allowing it to open once, I can't figure out why.

Comment: You can try to place the 3 subsequent lines in a callback from the load callback like so:
$('.viewer').load(window.location.pathname + 'edit.php', function(){ [other calls]});